# lombok : cannot find a simbol : build failed with gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, slf4j, lombok, annotation-processor

My setting is like this..

Ecliplse 2020-03,

gradle 6.3

lombok 1.18.12

**dependencies**

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```

**failed commands**

./gradle build -x test

./gradlew build -x test

When building the program with this settings, I always got the cannot find the symbol error .

The slf4j Tag also looks like that isn't understood by the build.gradle.

What should I try??
What' wrong with that??
Please help me find the cause of this problem..

Answer (score 0):

I tried all searched ways to solve the problem.
But the error message did not change anything.
After all, I found that the directory that I commanded "gradle build" is not the same with it of source code that I was working...
When I check the right directory everythin goes well.
Thanks.